# Applying a Color Transformation to very Pixel of a texture (Libgdx)

Tags: libgdx, colormatrix

A game I am currently developing uses a 5x5 matrix to change the colors of the image on a per pixel basis. I was wondering if anyone has developed an extremely fast algorithm for something like this.

For every Pixel(setPixel(sourcePixel * Matrix))

I have built my own algorithm for this by getting and setting pixels on pixmap then drawing a new pixmap from this through iterating every pixel with set/get pixel. I have found a reasonably fast algorithm for this (150 million pixels ~3 seconds), but I was thinking of another idea rather than using the pixmap but I am unsure of how to implement this. Libgdx provides a FileHandle.readBytes() method that reads image files (in my case PNG) to byte arrays. My thought was rather than creating a pixmap, read the byte array while iterating the pixels. While iterating I would be drawing a new pixmap meaning their really is no point for me to make one for the base pixmap in the first place. With tests I found that with my current algorithm, 70% of the time it takes is from the method (PixMap.getPixel(x, y), and I could bypass this by straight reading the byte array. I have looked into PNG readers for byte array's online but to no avail.
Note I am unable to use ImageIO due it being an android based game. Would it make it faster by reading the byte array data while iterating/ is it possible to do this?

In the code below, JList is basically a HashMap in this context

```
 private static JList<Integer, Pixmap> colorShiftImage(Pixmap p, JList<Integer, float[][]> cms){
        JList<float[][], Pixmap> tempList = new JList<>();
        for(int i = cms.size() - 1; i > -1; --i){
            tempList.add(cms.getInt(i), new Pixmap(p.getWidth(), p.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888));
        }
        for(int y = p.getHeight() - 1; y > -1; --y){
            for(int x = p.getWidth() - 1; x > -1; --x){
                int v = p.getPixel(x, y);
                if(v != 0) {
                    r = ((v & 0xff000000) >>> 24);
                    g = ((v & 0x00ff0000) >>> 16);
                    b = ((v & 0x0000ff00) >>> 8);
                    a = ((v & 0x000000ff));
                    for(int i = tempList.size() - 1; i > -1; --i) {
                        float[][] c = tempList.getIDList().get(i);
                        tempList.getInt(i).drawPixel(x, y, (((l((r * c[0][0]) + (c[1][0] * g) + (c[2][0] * b) + (c[3][0] * a) + c[4][0])) << 24)
                                | ((l((r * c[0][1]) + (c[1][1] * g) + (c[2][1] * b) + (c[3][1] * a) + c[4][1])) << 16)
                                | ((l((r * c[0][2]) + (c[1][2] * g) + (c[2][2] * b) + (c[3][2] * a) + c[4][2])) << 8)
                                | ((l((r * c[0][3]) + (c[1][3] * g) + (c[2][3] * b) + (c[3][3] * a) + c[4][3])))));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        JList<Integer, Pixmap> returnL = new JList<>();
        for(int i = tempList.size() - 1; i > - 1; --i){
            returnL.add(cms.getIDList().get(i), tempList.getInt(i));
        }
        return returnL;
    }




  public static int l(float v){
        if(v < 0)return 0;
        else if(v > 255)return 255;
        return (int) v;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you're trying to do, but you can access the byte buffer of the pixmap directly. ByteBuffer buf= pixmap.getPixels();  I've used it and got it working, so I can probably add some code in an answer if you need it.

Comment: Does the resulting image get used for something other than as a Texture? Because this would be super fast to do with the GPU which is designed for doing many math operations in parallel. You could do this on a FrameBuffer in a shader.

Comment: @funferret, I have looked into the byte buffer of the PixMaps, but I heard that the data they stored was in the native files and not in Java itself. If their was a way to access this data and manipulate its values directly than this is what I am after.

Comment: @Tenfour04, My end goal is to create a new texture to then render to the screen, if their is a faster way to do this operation on the GPU rather than a CPU to create the resultant texture than I am all ears to this. My end goal is to make several textures from an image, each with its own color matrix applied in fast manner.

Comment: So the five by five matrix is multiplied by the color like the color is a vector of length four, rgba?

Comment: Correct, (Rs, Gs, Bs, As) * Matrix = (Rd, Gd, Bd, Ad),  their are several Color Matrix pages online that describe it, I have not found any using them with java though

Comment: I would show my code, but its huge  and wrapped around other game logic, so it wont make much sense

Comment: I'll post some code tomorrow morning (about 10 hours from now), when I've recovered from the beers I've just had, of direct byte buffer data manipulation which I've used in one of my games. Then you should consider whether that is what you want to do or using shaders and FrameBuffers as @Tenfour04 suggests. I doubt there are any better options, not that we know exactly what it is you want to do, unless you post some code.

Comment: @funferret, I posted the code, hopefully this gives a better idea of what I am attempting to do. I am using decreasing loop as it seems to work ~10% faster for me in this operation.

Comment: The pixmap is the base image being copied, the JList contains information about the color matrixes to be used with the base pixmap.

Comment: I was talking to someone about shaders, I have decided to use this path, 1) Takes very little memory compared to the above strategy I have been using and 2) Far faster to load